# What is the running time for this function?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o, time-complexity, recurrence

I have 3 questions in this function ,

```
Sum = 0 
MyFunction (N)
        M = 1,000,000 
        If (N > 1)
                For I = 1 to M do
                        Sum = 0
                        J = 1 
                        Do 
                                Sum = Sum + J
                                J = J + 2
                        While J < N 
                End For
                If (MyFunction(N / 2) % 3 == 0)
                        Return (2 * MyFunction(N / 2))
                Else
                        Return (4 * MyFunction(N / 2))
                End If
        Else
                Return 1        
        End If
End MyFunction
```

**First question is** : What's the Complexity of the non-recursive part of code?

I think the non recursive part is that loop

```
For I = 1 to M do
                        Sum = 0
                        J = 1 
                        Do 
                                Sum = Sum + J
                                J = J + 2
                        While J < N 
                End For
```

and my answer is `M * log(n)` , but my slides say it's not `M * log (n)` !
I need explanation for this.

**The second question is:**  What's the correct recurrence for the previous code of MyFunction?

when I saw these lines of code

```
If (MyFunction(N / 2) % 3 == 0)
                        Return (2 * MyFunction(N / 2))
                Else
                        Return (4 * MyFunction(N / 2))
                End If
```

I think that it's `T(n) = T(n/2) + Theta(non-recursive)`,
because if will execute one of the 2 calls.

Again this answer is wrong.

**The third one is:** What's the complexity of MyFunction?

My answer based on the 2 questions is `T(n) = T(n/2) + M * lg n` 
and total running time is `M * lg n` .

Comment: For your first question: you should think of proportions. What happens if you give function twice as big `N`? Will its execution take twice the time, or something less?

Comment: hmm, I didn't understand what you mean.

I said log n because of the do-while loop, is this wrong ?

Comment: `do-while` loop has a role in the non-recursive part of complexity, you got that part right. But why did you prefer `log n`? How many steps will it take for the do while loop to execute?

Comment: It will be executed M times because the loop before it ?

Comment: ohhh, you mean that M is constant , and it will be only ( Theta(lg n) ) ?

Comment: Consider the following code: `while(j < N) j++;`. Assume `j=0` initially. Obviously, it will take `N` steps. Now assume `j` is incremented by two at each step. Now this `while` loop will take `N/2` steps. Now consider the outer `M` loop. The run-time is `M * N/2` not `M * log N`. Also, since M is constant in this case and we are talking about asymptotic complexity (as N goes to infinity), M and `/2` becomes insignificant, thus yielding a complexity of `O(N)`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at this one piece at a time.

First, here's the non-recursive part of the code:

```
For I = 1 to M do
     Sum = 0
     J = 1 
     Do 
         Sum = Sum + J
         J = J + 2
     While J < N 
End For
```

The outer loop will run Θ(M) times.  Since M is a fixed constant (one million), the loop will run Θ(1) times.

Inside the loop, the inner while loop will run Θ(N) times, since on each iteration J increases by two and stops as soon as J meets or exceeds N. Therefore, the total work done by this loop nest is Θ(N): Θ(N) work Θ(1) times.

Now, let's look at this part:

```
If (MyFunction(N / 2) % 3 == 0)
    Return (2 * MyFunction(N / 2))
Else
    Return (4 * MyFunction(N / 2))
End If
```

The `if` statement will make one recursive call on an input of size `N / 2`, and then depending on the result there will always be a second recursive call of size `N / 2` (since you're not caching the result).

This gives the following recurrence relation for the runtime:

> T(n) = 2T(n / 2) + Θ(n)

Using the Master Theorem, this solves to Θ(n log n).

Hope this helps!